# Downloading error through ad hoc (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an individual developer account. On my personal page, I added 2 more devices apart from mine. These devices belong to my coworkers. Also, I added these devices to my iOS Development provisioning profile. Next, I tried to deploy my app (after archiving it) through ad hoc. All devices were added to ad hoc provisioning profile too.

Then, I saved manifest.plist file and app_name.ipa file.

I downloaded .ipa file to the internet and made its own download link. I opened manifest.plist and substitute first link (which I indicated in Xcode during making manifest and .ipa files) on created in internet download link for .ipa file. After this, I downloaded the manifest.plist file on the internet and made its own download link. I copied this link and concatenated it with `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=`.
After that, I sent this link to my coworkers, and they tried to download the app, but during loading, an error occurred. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ad hoc builds are a way for you to share an app with testers privately, allowing the app to run on their devices. Those users don't "download" the ad hoc build from Apple. *You* email it to them or communicate it to them *yourself* in some way.

Comment: You might want to look at this section of my online book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_ad_hoc_distribution

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds more like a TestFlight build (app store) than an ad hoc build.